# Trying to filter msdb..sysjobs by job_id

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, varbinary

I'm attempting to determine the name of the SQL Server Agent Job that is currently running by comparing the output of `master.sys.dm_exec_sessions.program_name` to `msdb..sysjobs.job_id`

I'm using the following T-SQL to try to diagnose why I cannot get the results I want:

```
SELECT program_name, '|' + SUBSTRING(program_name,30,34) + '|' AS JobIDSubstring, t.text
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions s 
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests r on s.session_id = r.session_id
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) t
--  INNER JOIN msdb..sysjobsteps sj on SUBSTRING(program_name,30,34) = cast(cast(sj.job_id as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max))
WHERE 
    program_name like 'SQLAgent%' ;

SELECT CAST(job_id as varbinary(max)) as JobStepID, CAST(step_id as varbinary(max)) as StepID, *
FROM msdb..sysjobsteps;

SELECT program_name, '|' + SUBSTRING(program_name,30,34) + '|' AS JobIDSubstring, t.text
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions s 
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests r on s.session_id = r.session_id
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) t
    INNER JOIN msdb..sysjobsteps sj on SUBSTRING(program_name,30,34) = cast(cast(sj.job_id as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max))
WHERE 
    program_name like 'SQLAgent%' ;
```

Results:

[image]

The last query *should* return results, however it returns zero rows since the `JOIN` clause is clearly not working.  How should I construct this so the `JOIN` from `sys.dm_exec_sessions` to `msdb..sysjobsteps` works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop using `CAST` and use `CONVERT`. Specifically because, in this case, you need to use a certain style parameter in order to get the right string comparison (otherwise it is just converting `0xwhatever` to the string value represented by `0xwhatever`, which is not `0xwhatever`. Compare:

```
SELECT 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), 0x48656C6C6F21),
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), 0x48656C6C6F21, 1);
  ----- only difference -------------^^^
```

Results:

```
------   --------------
Hello!   0x48656C6C6F21
```

`Hello!` is actually the string represented by the binary value. The second column is just the binary value displayed as a string. Big difference!

With that in mind, change the join criteria on your last query to:

```
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps sj -- why leave out dbo?
  ON SUBSTRING(s.[program_name],30,34) = -- prefix your columns
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(34), CONVERT(VARBINARY(32), sj.job_id), 1) -- no need for MAX types here
  ------- this is the important piece ------------------^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try looking at `msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity`. This table includes the `session_id` and the `job_id` for actively running jobs. I would expect you could take that and then connect back into the sessions DMVs to get your information.

Comment: FYI, the session_id in msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity is related to the session_id in msdb.dbo.syssessions which represents the current invocation of SQL Agent.  The session_id in sys.dm_exec_sessions represents the SPID of a running job.